# JSON-Request to Jersey causes "400 Bad Request"

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I have a jersey server example, that works fine with XML, but does not work with JSON.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Path("JsonExample")
public class JsonExample {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Input {
        public String text;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public String test(Input i) {
        return i.text;
    }

}
```

If I send this xml request as `application/xml` to the server, everything works fine, the response is `a` (to `http://localhost:8080/App/rest/JsonExample` as `POST`)

```
<input><text>a</text></input>
```

I translated it to JSON at [utilities-online.info](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/?save=a638b0bd-28c4-48a6-9867-0da8419e0fd3-xmltojson#.VUzREeGHi-0) and sent it as `application/json` to the same URL, with same parameters, but got an error "400 Bad Request"

```
{
  "input": { "text": "a" }
}
```

Environment:

- Tomcat 7
- jersey 2.17

What I've tried:

- added `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs` to the `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` init-param
- enabled init-param `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` as `true`
- added dependency `com.sun.jersey`/`jersey-json`/`1.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing my question I saw an exception, that "input" is not expected as a field. The correct JSON-request has to be:

```
{ "text": "a" }
```